# Parsing ISO Duration with JSON.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a Web API project with the following settings in `Global.asax.cs`:

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat, 
        DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
    };

serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());

var jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter { SerializerSettings = serializerSettings };
jsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters[0].MediaTypeMappings[0]);

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters[0] = jsonFormatter;

WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

Despite all this, Json.Net cannot parse [ISO durations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

It throws this error:

> Error converting value "2007-03-01T13:00:00Z/2008-05-11T15:30:00Z" to
>   type 'System.TimeSpan'.

I'm using Json.Net v4.5.

I've tried different values such as "P1M" and others listed on the wiki page with no luck.

So the question is:

1. Am I missing something?
2. Or do I have to write some custom formatter?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and am now using this custom converter to Convert .NET TimeSpans to ISO 8601 Duration strings.

```
public class TimeSpanConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var ts = (TimeSpan) value;
        var tsString = XmlConvert.ToString(ts);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, tsString);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var value = serializer.Deserialize<String>(reader);
        return XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(value);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof (TimeSpan) || objectType == typeof (TimeSpan?);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the best solution

Comment: thanks for this! Feels a little odd to have XmlConvert in the Json parser but it works well.

Comment: Yeah, the really weird thing is a very similar approach using Xml functions is also what you need to use to accomplish this in Java as well.