# JSON.Net Iso Durations are not serialized/desrialized properly

Tags: c#, json.net, iso8601

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing ISO Duration with JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633588/parsing-iso-duration-with-json-net)

Given the following snippet,

**While Serializing**

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat };
settings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter()); 

var duration = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(duration, settings));
```

> **Outputs:** "00:01:00"
>   **Should output:** "PT1M"

**While Deserializing**

```
Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"Duration\": \"PT1M\"}", settings));
```

> **Fails**: Error converting value "PT1M" to type 'System.TimeSpan'. Path
>   'Duration', line 1, position 19.

And yet, this page - [Json.NET 4.5 Release 1 - ISO dates, Async, Metro build](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2012/03/20/json-net-4-5-release-1-iso-dates-async-metro-build.aspx) claims otherwise. What am I missing?

Comment: [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) works perfectly though. For the time being, switching to that instead.

Comment: I don't see mentioning of TimeSpan, only "writes dates as an ISO 8601" - so maybe it just does not support it... I think ISO8601 duration is much less commonly used than date-time...

Comment: Yeah. So much for implementing half the standard!

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, any resolution?

Comment: @JayTraband: other than switching to ServiceStack or writing your own handling, there is no solution as of right now.

Comment: Actually, I posted a TimeSpanConverter class that extends the JsonConverter 2 days ago, but it was deleted. I am using it in my application (www.breezejs.com) and it works well. Not sure how to get them to put my post back.