# DataContractJsonSerializer with TimeSpan is different on Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin.android

I have an existing Windows Phone and Windows Store App which both talk to a web service. All 3 are using DataContractJsonSerializer.

Now I'm porting my WP App to Android and run into an issue with the Android version of DataContractJsonSerializer.

On Windows a TimeSpan is serialized in [ISO 8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals), e.g. "PT0S".

On Android it is serialized as a _ticks object, e.g. {"_ticks":0}

Changing the existing applications and the web Service is a no go.

Are there any other compatible JSON serializers I can use to replace DataContractJsonSerializer in Xamarin? Any other Workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I believe in JSON.net the default format for DateTime is ISO 8601.

[Parsing ISO Duration with JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633588/parsing-iso-duration-with-json-net)

Looks like ServiceStack is your option, apparently.

Comment: It's not a DateTime, it's a TimeSpan that differs.